# How can I make this code for finding legal chess moves more efficient?

Tags: python, chess

I am trying to make a chess engine without use of the python chess libraries, so I can learn more about chess programming.
Have generated a set of pseudo legal moves (- castling and en passant) and have made a function to generate only the legal moves from the list.
my code for this function is here:

```py
def generateLegalMoves(currentPos, colourToMove):
    kingNumber = 1 if colourToMove == "b" else 9
    opponentColour = "w" if colourToMove == "b" else "b"
    legalMoves = []
    myKingSquare = currentPos.index(kingNumber)
    pseudoLegalList = GeneratePsuedoLegalMoves(currentPos, colourToMove)
    for pseudoMove in pseudoLegalList:
        newPos = makeMove(currentPos, pseudoMove[0], pseudoMove[1])
        newPosPsuedoLegalMoves = GeneratePsuedoLegalMoves(newPos, opponentColour)
        isLegal = True
        for j in newPosPsuedoLegalMoves:
            if j[1] == myKingSquare:
                isLegal = False
        if isLegal:
            legalMoves.append(pseudoMove)
    return legalMoves
```

How can I code a more efficient version?

Comment: how do you know it's not efficient now?

Comment: @ti7 I tested it up to a depth of 3 and it took over 10 seconds.

Comment: I would have probably coded this fundamentally different. I would've created a `class Piece` that has a method `def legal_moves` whose only job is to determine legal moves of a piece. I (probably) would've created a `class` for each piece type (pawn, bishop, knight, rook, queen, and king) with its color and current square that it is on and that overrides the `def legal_moves` method. I would have a `class Board` that keeps up with the piece instances. You can then create a Board method `def legal_moves()` that can return a list of pieces and their moves.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most efficient implementation. Your code is a little bit hard to read, but here is what I think I understand to be improvable.

First:

```
for j in newPosPsuedoLegalMoves:
    if j[1] == myKingSquare:
       isLegal = False
```

If `isLegal` is set to `False` once, there is no reason to continue the loop. You can `break` and move on. Otherwise, you continue to loop for no reason, even though you already know `isLegal` is `False`.

Second, you may want to switch to using a `Set` instead of a `List`, especially if you are going to go multiple depths. In general, the time complexity when working with `Sets` (search is O(1)) is much better than working with `Lists` (search is O(n)). See here: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120824/run-time-difference-for-in-searching-through-list-and-set-using-python) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993659/5181837) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872297/5181837)